# Setting an option to the content of a file in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I need to have one of

```
set foo=bar
```

or

```
set foo=baz
```

in `.vimrc`. I'd like to read either "bar" or "baz" from a certain file. That is, what one would do in `sh` with `foo=`cat file`` (I don't know how to escape backticks...). How does one do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let &foo = readfile('filename', '', 1)[0]
```

The `let &foo` syntax lets you set options to arbitrary expressions.

Comment: I'm sorry, the title was misleading. `foo` is an option, not a variable.

Comment: It's okay - `&foo` treats foo as an option.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks a lot.